# Tomcat-8.0.44: Why a SEVERE log "One or more Filters failed to start"

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

I installed Tomcat-8.0.44 and put a war file named bimserver.war in webapps folder. But when I ran the startup.bat routine, I got two Severe Log info:

```
24-May-2017 01:15:53.065 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
24-May-2017 01:15:53.068 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/bimserver] startup failed due to previous errors
```

It seems that some filters of tomcat failed to start. This prevented bimserver from starting. How should the filters be configured?

Comment: How *have* you configured the filters?

Answer (score 7):

Using Tomcat 8.5.30 on Ubuntu 18.04, I was getting the error:

```
08-Apr-2019 00:02:16.994 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

The details were in the log file: `/var/lib/tomcat8/logs/localhost.2019-04-08.log` (the same as `/var/log/tomcat8/localhost.2019-04-08.log`).

The details were:

```
08-Apr-2019 00:02:01.869 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [CorsFilter]
 javax.servlet.ServletException: It is not allowed to configure supportsCredentials=[true] when allowedOrigins=[*]
```

I was trying to use `*` for the `cors.allowed.origins` with `cors.support.credentials` set to `true`. Setting `cors.support.credentials` to `false` solved the problem.

Finding and checking the correct log file solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

As your log suggests (`Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file`), you should check Tomcat log, and then you can find the message starts with `Exception starting filter ...`.

Comment: Just for complement:
The logs in `/var/logs/tomcat8` don't show all stacktrace. Go to tomcat path to get full logs. The default instalations is in `/usr/share/tomcat8/logs`

Comment: In my case, there was no other log entry containing the actual error, localhost.date.log was empty.  My issue was that I was copying a new war file in place without properly cleaning out the app directory of the contents of the previous wars.

Answer (score 2):

Detailed logs on such exceptions can be found under `CATALINA_HOME/logs/localhost.<timestamp>.log`

Refer to latest timestamp log.

Sometimes, application specific logs(under tomcat logs) will also contain detailed info, depending upon application logging.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I haven't set my workspace to build automaticaly

in eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxQTa.png)